# Hairloss in cat, which appears to be anomalous

Tags: cats, biology, breeds, hairloss

I have a one-year-old, male, white Scottish Straight cat which is in good health, but has been losing hair for the past 6 months and still is. In my experience with other cats, in this case the amount of hair and the length of time  seem to be above average.

Is it a question of breed or possibly individual characteristics of the cat?

Comment: Are you talking about excessive shedding, or actual visible thin or bald areas?  If the latter, are these areas on the face between the eyes and ears?  If so, it's normal as a cat becomes mature to have the hair become thin in those areas.

Comment: @Kai , no, I am referring  to excessive shedding, there are no bold areas but the loss of hair is quite noticeable, but most of all it has been going on for quite a while.

Answer (score 5):

It is very hard to answer questions about shedding in cats as it is very variable in the different breeds.

Some cats will shed fur more or less continuously over the year and other cats will shed mostly in the spring and autumn.

When you brush your cat during shedding the amount of fur you get off from your cat can be amazing (it looks like you will have enough fur for a spare cat in about a week).

If your cat gets hairless spots or is itchy, you need to consult your vet to get it diagnosed and treated.

You should mention the hairloss to your vet at the next consultation; as it is now I do not think you need to worry about your cat's health.

[Here is an article on catcareofvinings.com](http://www.catcareofvinings.com/blog/all-cats-shed-but-whats-normal-and-whats-not/) about the difference between normal and pathological shedding.

Some information about the skin and fur of cats and dogs is also [in this PDF file](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0659/4529/files/SkinCoat_WhiteSheet6-5.pdf?6678352109863082785).